# How to better distinguish answers from questions when using the Answers module?

Tags: 7

Bare with me, I am not a programmer, and I'm using the [Answers](https://www.drupal.org/project/answers) module. I would like to make the background color of the ***answer*** content type a different color to distinguish it from the **question**.

So that when you browse both the question and the answer(s) (which the [Answers](https://www.drupal.org/project/answers) module shows below the actual question on the same page), they don't look too similar.

I know I can add the field label (of the body of each answer), but I'd like to figure this out.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your configuration, there are probably already classes supplied by default with Drupal.  Have you used Firebug to check the markup provided by Drupal by default?  ([video tutorial on how to use Firebug](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yYSSM3pNBTI))

If you do need to add a class, one quick way to add a class to a field is the [Field Group](http://drupal.org/project/field_group) module.  Navigate to the "Manage fields" page for the content type you wish to modify, create a new field group of type *div*, and then add the class and place the fields you wish to be "in" the class within it.

Comment: i love firebug even though i admit its a little over my head.  i will try the field group module, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The newest 7.x-4.0 version of the [Answers](https://www.drupal.org/project/answers) module comes with the (new) `Answers Theme` sub-module, which, out-of-the-box, transforms the (rather boring) vanilla display of a **Question** (and its related **Answers** below it), into a way more attractive look-and-feel. Such as the orange bubble that is added around the question (to better highlight it). Here is a screenprint that is pretty close to what's included in the newest version:

[image]

If you don't enable this sub-module, then you get a similar vanilla display (still). To see it at work, head over to this [example question](http://drupal.placeto.be/question/50) in its [demo site](http://drupal.placeto.be/module/answers)).

With this submodule enabled, it might no longer be needed to makeg the background color of the *answer* content type a different color (to distinguish it from the question to view both the answers and the question on the same page), since they don't look the same anymore, already out-of-the-box. Though you could still adapt the CSS (eg the orange bubble) to fit your preferences.

<sup>Disclosure: I'm a co-maintainer of [Answers](https://www.drupal.org/project/answers).</sup>